# Java Generics Incompatible Types

Tags: java, android, generics

I have 2 abstract classes that are extended, and another class that uses them:

-----Base-----

```
public abstract class HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse>
{...}
public abstract class HttpResponse<DATA_TYPE>
{...}
```

-----Extended-----

```
public class MockyTextRequest extends HttpRequest<MockyTextResponse>
{...}
public class MockyTextResponse extends HttpResponse<TextWithTitle>
{...}
```

----Utility------

```
public class HttpClient
{...
    public <REQUEST_TYPE extends HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE>, RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<RESULT_TYPE>, RESULT_TYPE> RESPONSE_TYPE synchronicRequest(@NonNull final REQUEST_TYPE httpRequest, @Nullable final Object tag) throws IOException, HttpException, ParseException
    {...}
...}
```

---

When I compile, I get:

> error: incompatible types: inference variable RESPONSE_TYPE has
>   incompatible upper bounds HttpResponse,MockyTextResponse

on

```
MockyTextResponse httpResponse = HttpClient.get().synchronicRequest(new MockyTextRequest(), null);
```

Any Ideas?

---

Stange fact, this call

```
public <REQUEST_TYPE extends HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE>, RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<RESULT_TYPE>, RESULT_TYPE> void request(@NonNull final REQUEST_TYPE httpRequest, @Nullable final Object tag, @Nullable final Listener<REQUEST_TYPE, RESPONSE_TYPE> listener)
{...}
```

called

```
HttpClient.get().request(new MockyTextRequest(), MainActivity.this);
```

Works ok

Full code here in [github](https://github.com/155martinmoreno/HttpClient)

Comment: Do you actually need `RESULT_TYPE` inside `sychronicRequest`? Btw what version of Java are you compiling on?

Comment: It's Java 7. I do use RESULT_TYPE inside the function to avoid a cast

Comment: Well, I might be able to come up with a clever solution but I would say don't hold your breath. This looks like an inference bug, Java 7 was rife with small things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inference algorithm seems to not be able to infer the type of `RESPONSE_TYPE`. It *looks* like all three type parameters *should* be given by `MockyTextRequest`.

I'm not *exactly* sure why this is the case with respect to the specification but it has to do with the "nesting".

The error can be reproduced in the following way:

```
// same error on this line
// C (String) is not inferred
m(new ArrayList<List<String>>());

// the compiler is able to infer B from A
// but not C from A
static <A extends List<B>, B extends List<C>, C> void m(A a) {}
```

This is the kind of thing that's been fixed in Java 8:

- [Ideone Java 7 compilation](http://ideone.com/HT08js)
- [Ideone Java 8 compilation](http://ideone.com/FNJvkd)

You *could* provide a witness:

```
MockyTextResponse httpResponse =
    HttpClient.get().
        <MockyTextRequest, MockyTextResponse, TextWithTitle>
        synchronicRequest(new MockyTextRequest(), null);
```

Or a few ways to loosen up the type parameters:

1.

```
public <
    RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<RESULT_TYPE>,
    RESULT_TYPE
> RESPONSE_TYPE synchronicRequest(
    final HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE> httpRequest, final Object tag)
```

2.

```
public <
    REQUEST_TYPE extends HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE>,
    RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<?>
> RESPONSE_TYPE synchronicRequest(
    final REQUEST_TYPE httpRequest, final Object tag)
```

3.

```
public <
    REQUEST_TYPE extends HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE>,
    RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<? extends RESULT_TYPE>,
    RESULT_TYPE
> RESPONSE_TYPE synchronicRequest(
    final REQUEST_TYPE httpRequest, final Object tag)
```

From your descriptions, it seems like #1 is the best. (#2 and #3 are basically the same because `RESULT_TYPE` doesn't get inferred anyway.)

---

Another way would be to define `HttpRequest` like the following:

```
class HttpRequest<
    RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<RESULT_TYPE>,
    RESULT_TYPE
>
```

And then:

```
class MockyTextRequest
extends HttpRequest<MockyTextResponse, TextWithTitle>

public <
    REQUEST_TYPE extends HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE, RESULT_TYPE>,
    RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<RESULT_TYPE>,
    RESULT_TYPE
> RESPONSE_TYPE synchronicRequest(
    final REQUEST_TYPE httpRequest, final Object tag)
```

But this probably makes some of your code a lot more verbose.

---

As a side note, you should [avoid raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664) when you can:

```
//                                                  vvv
class HttpRequest<RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse<?>>
```

Comment: Well, using "...RESPONSE_TYPE extends HttpResponse..." instead does work, but forces me to cast some vars inside the body.

Comment: Strange thing is, another almost-the-same function does work (see my edit)

Comment: Yes the one in your edit works because `RESULT_TYPE` can be inferred from the argument. See my intro comments about the nesting.

Comment: It is called int almost the exact same way "HttpClient.get().request(new MockyTextRequest(), MainActivity.this);"

Comment: But you're passing a `Listener<REQUEST_TYPE, ...>` to the method, where `REQUEST_TYPE` is not "nested" in another inferred type.